# Is it possible to recreate this visual in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I currently have a report that kind of looks like this in Excel. Is it possible to create the same structure with the color formatting in Power BI? Especially with the Percentage Sale and Sales Amount below each other in the row?

[image]

I tried using Matrix visual but I kind of run into a problem since the columns would have different format types - whole number and percentage. Also tried with showing columns in rows, while using Percentage Sale and Sales Amount as two columns. But then I would have problems with the color formatting. Any ideas how to achieve it in Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

Its actually simple ..... just follow these steps

```
1.) You can use matrix or table both... but I preferred tables
2.) Go to format Visual (In visualistation  you can see 3 option... its the middle one)
3.) After that click on values.
4.) Now  you can se background color , alterante background color etc
5.) Just choose it acc to preferences
```

If you want a bar label in a selected column then,

```
6.)In build format, right click on your column (which you want to customize)
7.)Select conditional formatting
8.)Now you can change color
9.)apply this. After that you can see your data of selected columns are showing grid bars
```

Comment: But how do you create the columns that contains both percentage and total numbers? For example I create a goal column but I can't have both percentage and total numbers Format in it. If I alternate the columns to rows then I have to create Percentage Sale and Sales Amount columns which contains all numbers for goal, latest, forecast etc. Then the color formatting doesn't work.

Comment: I think you are confused a little bit..  like why dont you try using two data labels and apply one for percentage and another one for number

Comment: I need two columns for that right? It's not possible to use different type of formating in one column? If I have two columns then for example goal total and goal percentage will be shown next to each other and not below anymore like in the excel.